# Google Calendar crashes because I added an event with endTime earlier than startTime

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

So I added an event to my Google Calendar using the CalendarProvider according to this example.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#add-event

However, I mistakenly set the endTime as earlier than the startTime. Now when I search on my own Calendar (through the actual Google Calendar app) for an event with a similar name to the faulty one I added, it crashes. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: clear the cache on calendar on phone might work, however you might loose some stuff, unless it sync online. If you know the ID of the event you could make your app delete em if that does not work. If you sync maybe you can delete the event online, from gmail or where ever its stored.

Comment: I tried clearing the cache. Didn't seem to work. If I do clear data on the Google Calendar app, will this affect my events in the cloud? I'm afraid that it will delete the events from my actual calendar and not just locally on my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. Had to pull all events for my calendar and manually look for the event_id that was causing the problem (because I never recorded it in the first place unfortunately). I then just posted a delete query to the CalendarProvider, and my Calendar now works properly again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to app setting-> Clender storage -> clear app data

check this link  "http://www.synccell.com/support/kb/questions.php?questionid=51" for more detail